# Should there be a gcc tag?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags

I recently asked a [question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/152759/vectorizing-the-product-of-an-array-of-complex-numbers) that is at least in part specific to gcc. That is, the way the C code is written will be different for different compilers.  This is because different compilers are able to vectorize different code.

Should there be a gcc tag so that people with the appropriate gcc specific expertise will know to look at it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like a tag that some people might reasonably want to search/filter for, so I think it should be created.

Answer (score 6):

To be honest, you would probably be better off asking that question on Stack Overflow.  The question contains a short code snippet (which could be considered an [MCVE](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)), and you are asking a specific question about that code (how to get GCC to vectorize it) rather than for an open-ended critique.

That probably explains why no [gcc](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gcc) tag has been created on Code Review prior to this — it's too specific.  And I see that you have asked [a similar question on Stack Overflow before](//stackoverflow.com/q/41639654/1157100), with [gcc] and [auto-vectorization] tags.

Comment: You could be right but I am also asking for any advice about the code which people might have.

Comment: I would still be in favor of removing it (I only added [meta-tag:status-completed] since it was already created).

Comment: I agree, if only because the audience you'd be hoping to target with this question is more active on Stack Overflow. I'd like to see Code Review grow to handle low-level performance optimization questions (on working code, of course), but as things stand right now, I think Stack Overflow is one's best shot at a good answer.